# Google CSE - search parameter

Tags: javascript, google-search

I'm changing the search engine of my site to Google CSE.

I use "s = term" on my site and also generates urls as /search/term.html

Google can not recognize it. What must change in code?

> var queryParamName = 's';

```
 <div class="row-fluid sc-col row-dynamic-el" style="margin-bottom:40px;"><div class="row-fluid"><div id='cse' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div></div>
<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'pt', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var customSearchOptions = {};
var orderByOptions = {};
orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('01111111111:111111111', customSearchOptions);
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
options.enableSearchResultsOnly();
options.setAutoComplete(true);
customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
function parseParamsFromUrl() {
var params = {};
var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
var keyValuePair = parts[i].split('=');
var key = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0]);
params[key] = keyValuePair[1] ?
decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) :
keyValuePair[1];
}
return params;
}
var urlParams = parseParamsFromUrl();
var queryParamName = 's';
if (urlParams[queryParamName]) {
customSearchControl.execute(urlParams[queryParamName]);
}
}, true);
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using V1 code and not the default V2 code.

I can not comment for V1 but for V2 code, visit *Look and feel* section in your google [cse control panel](https://cse.google.com), select appropriate layout and get the code (V2). I use *Results only* layout and made my own custom search box. Here is how my set up work for custom query parameter:

#### Search box

> I have custom css stylesheets for `div` id and class tags: searchbox2, searchcont2 and searchString2 which you need to replace with your stylesheet properties. Custom query parameter is defined under `name=s` in `form` section.

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
<div id="searchbox2" style="margin:0 auto; display: table;">
<div class="searchcont2">
    <form role="search" method="get" action="https://www.example.com/search/">
        <input id="searchString2" name="s" placeholder=" Search" type="text">
    </form>
</div></div>
</div></div>
```

If you are using other search layout, i.e., *two-page* or *two-column*, you can use following for your searchbox code with `data-queryParameterName` will take custom search query term.

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-resultsUrl="http://www.example.com/search/"
```

data-newWindow="true" data-queryParameterName="s">

For HTML5 pages, **google cse requires class attribute to be set to `gcse-XXX`**, e.g., `div class="gcse-searchbox"` else search results may not load as expected. See more at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5

#### Search results

> Add your google cse *resultsonly* code at a defined search page, e.g., https://www.example.com/search/ and replace `<GOOGLE CSE CX ID>` with your cse cx id. Same as searchbox, HTML5 page should have proper `div` class property, e.g., `<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"` in following case:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '<GOOGLE CSE CX ID>';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only">
</div></div>
```

Cheers!